# Brake lines and bold text using string format in C#

Tags: c#, string.format

I want to be able to make brake lines and bold name, startdate, enddate, rostersize and info.

This is my code.

```
private void FillEventInfo(Event e)
{
        txtBoxEventInfo.Text = String.Format(
                "Navn: {0} Startdate: {1} Enddate: {2} Rostersize: {3} Info: {4} ",
                e.Name, 
                e.StartDate, 
                e.EndDate, 
                e.RosterSize, 
                e.Description
            );
}
```

Answer (score 4):

If you want to format text, you need to use a `RichTextBox`, not a `TextBox` (which only supports plain text).

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to format separate words with different decoration. Try to use separate labels\textboxes with different font settings like this:

```
private void FillEventInfo(Event e)
{
    txtBoxEventInfo.Font = new Font(<someFontFamily>, 16);
    txtBoxEventInfo.Text = String.Format("Navn: {0} Startdate: {1} Enddate:{2} Rostersize: {3} Info: {4} ", e.Name, e.StartDate, e.EndDate, e.RosterSize, e.Description);

    txtBoxSomeOtherEventInfo.Font = new Font(<someOtherFontFamily>, 22);
    txtBoxSomeOtherEventInfo.Text = "Some other text"
}
```

To brake line use predefined constant - **Environment.NewLine**

```
...
var textWithBrakeLine = string.Format("Text {0} with {0} brake {0} line", Environment.NewLine);
...
```